# Why wall is rendered like this and Why rendered lighting look so pixelated

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

[image: Why wall is render like this and why rendered lighting look so pixelated.]
Why wall is render like this and why rendered lighting look so pixelated
How to fix this.

Comment: Hello, why do you mean by "like this"? As for the grainy look, if you're using Cycles, you probably need to increase the Sampling for Render, but maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: The light artifacts look to me like you have a fairly high amount of subdivision on the glass, but shading set to flat. In _Object Mode_, try right clicking, with the glass selected, and set shading to smooth. The pinching effect on the bottom of the glass can be remedied by beveling those edges, before subdividing. And, as already suggested by @moonboots, the graininess can usually be remedied by increasing the sampling, and/or enabling denoising. These are educated guesses, and to get a proper answer, please clarify you problem, and possibly share your blend file.